# Discussing suggested edits/justifying an approval

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I was working through some suggested edits when [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7861087) popped up.
At first I wanted to reject it, but after some thinking and reading it a couple of times I came to the conclusion that the edit was likely from the author himself, who probably just wasn't logged in.
The edit comment "replied to tab and pinwar13" really suggests that this is the case.
So I thought I'd let the edit pass.
However, as you can see at the link posted above, three other users rejected the edit, saying

> This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.

Now is there any good way for me to contact those others, since they obviously don't share my conclusion?
Or should I just have rejected the edit? I know it would have been better for the author to log in and do his edit just like that, but he didn't do that, and there is also no way for me to contact him and tell him to do so, is there? Especially since he won't event get a notice that his edit was rejected, because the edit is not tied to his account.

So, what should I do

1. with anonymous edits that look like they're from the author himself?
2. if I feel the need to justify an approval? A rejection displays a reason, whereas an approval does not, which can make it look like a user just clicked "Approve" without one second of thought, even though he has a good reason to approve the edit. He just can't share it.

Comment: You can discuss unsure edits on [this chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58120/please-dont-approve-minor-or-invalid-edits) , although, lately there aren't many users here.

Comment: Surely if a user hasn't bothered to log in then the edits should be treated as if they came from a random person and rejected as such.

Comment: Anyone can create a new account that shares the same username - we can't verify if it is the same user or not though so just treat it as though it isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP in this example is new (1 rep), and until they have 50 rep, they won't be able to comment on others' posts... which appears to be what was desired. (As noted by Sigusa, if the OP was logged in to the account that posted, they should be able to comment on the question & its answers.)

That's just one more guess at what motivated the edit, and is no more true than the guess that the edit is by the OP-not-logged-in. I think it's also equally irrelevant.

**Based on the evidence, the edit is invalid, and should be rejected.**

<s>To help a new user over the low-rep speed bump, you could flag the edit for a moderator, and suggest that the supplemental notes be added as a comment. The worst that will happen is that the flag gets rejected.</s>

Revised opinion: While rejecting the edit, add a comment to the OP guiding them to add comments as a way to converse with respondents.

> I know it would have been better for the author to log in and do his edit just like that, but he didn't do that, and there is also no way for me to contact him and tell him to do so, is there?

Sure there is... add your suggestion in a comment to the question. (However, the edit would still be invalid, and better as a comment.)

Comment: You're right, I could have commented on the question directly... I'm probably gonna do that if I ever encounter such a situation again. But as far as I know, an asker can comment on everything on his own question, regardless of reputation, or not? Also, updating the question (with new information, as he did) seems to be common practice and not unwelcome here. However, **DavidG**'s comment convinces me.

Comment: This one was pretty uncommon - the edit had more info as well as a response to another user, which would normally be a comment. I was looking at the response, mainly.

Comment: I don't think a mod can comment for someone. THey can convert answers to comments though...

Comment: @Deduplicator - so much for their god-like powers! I think you're right though.